# Ajax Update Delete

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html table which is populated with data through ajax/jquery and php. So far, I've made an insert/select functionality to the website.

Now I want to add update/delete. I was thinking of adding buttons to each results row with value=table_column_id then populating empty textboxes if the user clicks the "EDIT" button or throwing a dialog asking for confirmation if the user clicks the "DELETE" button.

Is this a good idea or is there a better way? If so, can you explain how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of powerful, well known and very good plugins that handle this kind of thing for you.
Take a look at:

- [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net)
- [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com)

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks lot. Will check them out
Do you know any tutorials that cover what I am looking for? I would like to know to do it myself, future use are the plugins you linked.

Comment: I didnt know anything offhand, but a quick google search of "jquery ajax add data" gave the following link, which covers at least the basic client/server/ajax functionality:

[Insert and Load Record using jQuery and Ajax.](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/05/insert-and-load-record-using-jquery-and.html)

Comment: Problem is, the buttons I create are dynamic therefor I can't get an onclick event to work. Thanks for the link

Comment: Try binding an event to the button after you create it. Or look at [jquery's delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)